# Define Intersect / Union as tag on interface property

Tags: typescript, typeorm

Below I am trying to create a special type for use with [Typeorm](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=141&pc=2#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAVQHYEsD2SAqaCSSwwBOAzjAMZjpIA8CAfHALyhytwAUCcMAHgUgBNicAIZIIcAPwcA1gC5EASiYMAbmhQC4CpDFVFlvfkI7t5cFEgBmRODmWM1Ggcuk5tcXfsKhQkWIioGADSMBDE1JgMjHCY3HwwgsJx0jJhaFaxHl5EANx%200PAAymCEKBTIVAASMAA2sIQATJEANLEAgrW10VkAZHAACiKElCK11ABK5GiEAtQAojxktQCuAjC0QUih4ZGd3W1pEBmxdG0rgjBWljACdHQFASVlFVs19UStHV09cUaJJhScGe5TAlQw7wazUwbUw%20wYOj0eUexVKoPBNCiTGBaNe1TqDS%20UV84EKcB2ESxMSOJ0wKLgADUxisYJTfgBtCmROgAXXpGKZq1Z3OxGOweAIJHIlAw1EFLLZDxA-MuVhFMUWyzWGxhcAu62uujuJP88AAwmhVgBbJDtQTYgDeokEkgUYgkAF96RbrUgAPKER1wGau52e72WlY2zCFL4AWXixmETrEAlD7raIbd4jgHt%20cH6KZdCjj7IA5KmyzzM4RQ6WyzMq7n6QARGA%20qOY-P-JJwDvR2OWGyBhBtIe2ADiDGkXAUdNJATb-dtXXVcCd7IGFiQcBpmUwPIUS8jNsim55DC9ypAvCgMzAcGWImIwgt%20BEFHXLFEAHMYAplxjWBqGINEkB-NoizTBQyxWUhCDLXMlVYJARCtf8%20xPLBY1AspwMg4Naxg2pnzAAA5NCYEQgAfOAy2uEhyMoxC82-BjQIo9CAKwoCNlwywIPXZ1oLokiOOYmtQzLVD0JY5C4DEpiuMw31eJAsDBKgqT2KUqjJJgmSqKQ784KIbjVNjJAowAIyIAiszo0zCBwAQ5JM%20CXPMzs1Ksq1bMINohIc2D4LckAr1AAB6SK4HaMizSqP0JnJMJiBJSKACoMrgKBCDQVRNFZPUtmDTJU13VK2isGZRBy4ZKDIFYSMDXK0CgOAMsi%20k7QEClIU%20XUtx7Ew91OUVVTPAYeUTAFk2E9Mcw9KRYnPctK2mxFvCVU1YsELlBpm3tRqpYqZCQNAAHcd2G4Qer6gkBraAZp2Kg0bi0BQ7tS-rCC%20Z7QEM4goA-eAvvCITvx2xY0KgWoYHabEwYiN8wA-MA2mk5j5KhngYbhgAhRG9tS6gUbRjGdM4qilQikBMuy1qCvWYQLioUrhIq8I2gulAwAACxyvL2qODquoXUHBAGVZiH2p7DpG9J9x6ZADWoLdaKRv77gByigZB3betSqW4K-EBWBxvH4aJgRjZlkmyYoDHDLLbGyWhq1YZgQmYh622uQd9G6MprHIbd3GPbhs1rb9%202MFRx3HNCmn0qywX8sKlmSpOGqjmIKqapEOqRnKJrhjT9rOvpANZcGeXhGO5WJswc866Coiw1zZbm6m8tGw2zwkUIJVAeBsh4Gr1KIbNuALYjq2Ygn3YA6dkPp9nz3vbgRfkbj8mg5QRiqZd0BafptOmaKpG4AAai3wgKVF7rBG3v7W4b8bVc1waGFol-v%20H3Wo8JYCG3lPc2YdLYIx9s-e%20sd3wJ0xrJV2AR3Yb2ti-Ze%209D6r1PqnRmGcDY7FtjfO%20D9K7iwNrbP%20csbqc1pI3T%20ktpY12enAX%20sDdj-x1uhPWY9KHS1AU6UOKDw6eygfwuCGDd4IOdsg%20AqCCbRwERwne8DA70QPuJJBJ90oxTiglJKgwhZpWvDtAAMmgMgMgdgZEwF8YIPRghv0VlkaQTjNpEBNGSIodQrADCFq-Wh78YgDHKDILW3DWRAOBL4-xbUwEzwgXPcRPjah%20ICZgxB1NhHyNEYomIqT0ltVJtI9RwdtHhS8QEX2xjAkJCOi4k6oSrFfAsVYmxVg7G6i-k9e4ACeHRJqW1OaOS4AKPnpQ2pmTZGjPGZvIZUBVHxzKZo3Sx9KmmLJL7aWcTFl1KTHQpW2JmnhN1G06xisultG2XBFhfTIm8OAbbXZyZZl5ImTc4gLySlqJXhU8BIjLbzKYXBb5mTynZLXkkz2UdoE2x2VM0pGMnLrNpjtAM3yDpBMaT0E5rTLEXOOJ0r41DBj3JACPfWGLjGmwBbkyB2JqXDJ%20csv5kK6VjPeZvJlezwWrKPnIzlltYV3zBUixORBUVVPkbUUgnyWHOKJWNDUSxVjrGoMda5IK7acN6dtN2sr4basxTQ%20pCslVNLCfi9plyvjzENfKkm-9%20lRP1vauVxqaUOjeQyjUDrPXMumavDlczsTuqNfC0FiLflYK0eyxJgK54ivDZ8sVMaQqSuTpslBhrSVDTNfXHFYbVXag1Y0rVkadWUj1fScNPLq212xRa3FVqzkEo6VcsZuaVFa21hSwBbru0vNpQm%20lySw1DujayuiMyoWJrQX60g9aWV7w0dg-5o6hVJonUuwgabp0ZoQlm%20k%20MVgoFqAIOMRA-y-SxQWw5yqcQvDBFsagqbanfzYaKj9Nb%200DP1qe89l7r22G9dPaKsQ%20YoGEBdGYMgYNQbIALaDcAfxoDQAIOQ34yAYFAqIBQgGL1XsIDeldMisaOm-ChSiMFMB8zQFaZ8cApg-h-CgMsLRvxXlYBBujKHYOEHg3AC6iHkPCDQxhrD08cNIDw9ZAjZ6iMgd%20kGpBlHp6sAhbR%20jjHiAcaowpUiVMYKEBgKx9jnHp7cbgLxqDwgrAiHPQh8oYnUPocw9%20CDMm8NkAU0B4jpHVPU3UzxmK1HlJljowxpjLG2P6fA2FuAWm6JRd0-F0LbBFLGboqZ8z6WbMxSvGiskhG5gnTFLgfARBSAUCoNQDcW5LAPoPH5pTJHHpktzOyY6F4HnRNKyOnaVpsSlbI2AeS3mHwiAUMNmIYG2CeBoylnTMWzNxbaBBkTEgUP8xQ2ReYDJ5gTAAISSFO8drjJ8gA) called `ColumnType`.

In `Typeorm` we define an object with properties like this, I left out the column specific decorators, note `strictPropertyInitialization` needs to be turned off for this to work.

```
export class Contact {
  age: ColumnType<string, { and?: 'user' }>
  name: ColumnType<string, { or?: 'lastName' | 'firstName' }>
  firstName: ColumnType<string, { and?: 'lastName', or?: 'name' }>
  lastName: ColumnType<string, { and?: 'firstName', or?: 'name' }>
  user: ColumnType<number, { or?: 'userId' }>
  userId: ColumnType<number,  { or?: 'user' }>
}
```

As you can see with `ColumnType`, I am trying to find a way to define the relations within this Entity by using `and` and `or` type properties. These "markers" help describe the relation a given property has with other properties.

I've put together a lot of code to try and get a `Build<T>` generic working, in which I would be able to pass Contact and output a type that describes these `and` and `or` relations. It's a very big chunk of code, however the main issue I am having is with the very end.

I've boiled the code down to a generic called `BuildMerger<T, P>` which takes `Contact`, and the one of it's keys (`P`).

```
type BuildMerger<T, P extends keyof T> = StrictUnion<AndPlusProps<T, P> | OrProps<T, P>>
namespace BuildMerger {
  // This works which is good:
  const a: BuildMerger<Contact, 'name'> = {
    name: 'Thomas Reggi',
  }
  // This works which is good:
  const b: BuildMerger<Contact, 'name'> = {
    firstName: 'Thomas',
    lastName: 'reggi',
  }
  // This fails which is good:
  // const c: BuildMerger<Contact, 'name'> = {
  //   name: 'Thomas Reggi',
  //   firstName: 'Thomas',
  //   lastName: 'reggi',
  // }
}
```

So now it would seem all I need to do is run every property of contact through this, and make an intersection.

```
type Build<T> = UnionToIntersection<{ [P in keyof T]: BuildMerger<T, P> }[keyof T]>
namespace Build {
  type m = Build<Contact>
  const a: m = {
    name: 'Thomas Reggi', // why is this NEVER!?!?!
  }
}
```

However this doesn't work.

Here's the full set of code

> [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=5&pc=51#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIJJ2BATgZwgGNhk4AeGAPigF4BYAKChagAoYoIAPHOAE3xQAhnBBQA-OwDWALlgBKOjQBuSBPyjy4EFXiU8%20g9mzlQEcAGZ4oGJbVXr%20SqRi1Qde3EyahIsRBQAaQgQfHJUGlooVC5eCAEhWKlpUKRLGPdPPABuX3BoAGVgXAQSeDIACQgAG0hcACYIgBoYgEEamqjMgDIoAAVhXFJhGvIAJWIkXH5yAFFuIhqAV34ISkC4ELCIjq7W1JB0mKpW5YEISwsIfioqfP9i0vLN6rq8FvbO7tjDBONklAnmVgBUUG96k1UK1UHsaNpdLkHkUSiCwRRInQgaiXlVavVPpEfIw-NBtuFMdFDsdUMioAA1UbLCAUn4AbXJESoAF06ejGSsWVysej0FgcARiKQUOQBczWfdGHyLpZhdEFktVutoVBzmsrjpbsTSVAAMJIFYAWzgbQEWIA3iIBBJ5KJxABfOnmq1wADyuAdUGmLqdHq9FuW1tQBU%20AFk4kYhI7RPwQ27WsHXWIoO6flA%20snnfJY2yAOQp0vcjO4EMl0vTSs5ukAEQg3sjGLzf0SZojUZjFmsAZgrUHNgA4jQpJx5LSSQUoK329a9mqoI62f1zHAoNSMqhufIl32MZvuTRPUrGDwwNNgFAlsJ8EJzdhhCR10wWMIAOYQeTLmgMb4KicA-q0hapvIpbLIQuCljmiosHAwiWv%20vY%20tGkDkCBpRgRBQY1tBNRPsAAByqEQAhAA%20UCllcBDkZRCG5l%20UAMSBFFoQBJ5YesuEWOB65OlBdEkZxzHViGpYoWhLFIVA4lMdxGEdnxOGgUJkHSRxylUVJ0GyVRiFsbBeA8ZhMZwJGABGeAEZmdFmbgGD8PJplwa5FlqVZtn2SwjqOTBcHuYwl5MAA9BFUBtGRpqVL64xQOSxIRQAVGlUBgLgSAqBoLK6psQYZCmu6hPgrSWNMIhZUMpBEMsJEBtlSBgFAaURXStr8OSEIfDqW7dsYe4nCKKoRGeCb-EmIlptm7qSDEZ5lhW3JZIiuCKia3WcgNU09iNlKFdIcBIAA7juQ1CDt5V9bgnz9FOhX6tcmjyDdYR3Q9ipGfgYDvtAH0zWxJoLKhYA1BAbRYkD5CvsA77AK0MnMQpoPcODkMAEIwwInLw4jyO6VxVGKuFjDpZlLV5WsQjnGQxUiWVYStGdCDAAAFllOVtYc7WdfO-jdf0Kz4LtrSDfEB1pPu3TwPq5BbrRsMDXcTC-f9RCA3j5Ui7Bn7MFA6OY1DuP8HrYvlXDKAIyQyNGaWaMLmDloQxAOPRMLov4zbhN0cTqMg87GOu5DppmxbPtvnbTkhWTqUZdzuX5XTRXHNVhwVex1XCLVwxlI1QxJ21HV0v64sDPtw0y6N0Ty5cE39GtV3CY5bo5otqDLfW8FrQiXg-ZRf0A1A5flcJQf%20C7bvQ9EY87ATMco3JTtTyHbse6PuBR7bSP%20wgjEk47TDk5TSc0wVQNQAA1Fv5L811AjzxSEtV0Ih1y%20NKsSzQtHP99g80LDy1jFJ%2029x6OkntAaekNZ6gP4P-Ree9l6kygVAGB7szaIN9kvAOK8T4JypjlC%2010dYgAtjfO%2049S6C21ubUW-89otw-mNBWXtYIV0elAP%204Cdiq0ASyTWdCLbPwnobY2odTaewECI3h4QkH20DuI4OJtN7sPwNg6OyC8GoLCqlaKsV4qJQGDzfAxoFwABkkBEGkNsdIqBPhBG6EEN%20zMaSLRcf3PA5jHi1EsP0HmD1XEsOiP0Mo0hvrqyHkIoEfiAmtTESwCRM8sSFDiYEhRdEHar2gevbGqT0mtWtloomB8JL4L0VebaMjTFBOYTXI6YSbGfCsTYuxlgHE6m-gMO4AjgHCNMYko2KjJFwOFrUzJKDj7KLXqoiOEycHaLKXpaZ5Nqn0NgvEsAL9K71KOLLLETSIk6labYmWnTWjqM4b0qJQCYnqK2UmNBGCxkyNFo84pu9FEVKSSMjeEd3kLJKfvQ%20SjfmzMkeHaRGz8AfMmc5VZPjoD%20g%20UwqW1d9m1wGOElp1izn7IuVQvhP81aMA1iPFFgz7TPLyVIrecLFnfN0eC3Jcy564AZcC%20iyyj45PQbSqF9KgVfNjngRFVTnY1EIFcq2aLExuIOeqRYKw1jkEOpct5HDZUkrpHMKVUNNWwtqXK6aCqsVHNxW085nw9XSsNdc0l5KQG2oNTCx5BsWX8pNnAl1DzhV%20ymXyjBm9fWGs5SK7loKfnDIhW7QVoa3X%20qXgi%20OEqp76sYa-PZNJugahVesdV8DI7ap6VtSVhBKWtR2ZLeVITsXNJOXi9phKXWZtLX0mJraOVUppd6rEXbw0Buyb2yRIaM3dqrZ8gNOjpmeowfG8dg7k1xwIWm6AWNlgIBqPwWMeA-z3RNdLTFR1gS4hlH6ydqtuFCsvTqsl0SR4bq3TuvdNhqWGyijEDmCAhBnWmNIX936iBcx-VAH8SAkD8FkGxIgKAQIiHkE%207du7cD7qnUvbJDo2LIUotBVAHMkCWifFASYP4fwIFLM0Nil4WCfvw6Bv9uAANQDOkBkDQhwOQeg4bWDcB4M2UQ5u5Dr77qTMw9Ed9rB2I8tw3RfDhGnyUew4pUiJNoK4AgGRijVHDY0agHR79QhLDCC3YBso7GwMQag2xT9vH4NEEE8%20lDaGxOoywx%206KOGVKlnk0RoQpHyNKY86wHReGCN%20aC7RzzKnynoVLBprTkX9PRUvGshcSHZhHVFJgbAeBCAkDIOQDcW4LBmoPI54TqH%20o-xzGyQ655bmCMfUJzQkmY3QEtFiDL6HgAKTs-eYQ8hOsSeU0ZMLCn-OacC60T9rHxCgc5qBsicx6RzHGAAQgkJt9b1GT5AA)

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> =
    (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never

type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
type StrictUnionHelper2<T, TAll> = T & Partial<Record<Exclude<UnionKeys<TAll>, keyof T>, undefined>>
type StrictUnionHelper<T, TAll> = T extends T ? StrictUnionHelper2<T, TAll> : never;
type StrictUnion<T> = StrictUnionHelper<T, T>

type Keys<T> = keyof T
type Values<T> = T[Keys<T>]
type UnionValues<T> = UnionToIntersection<Values<T>>

type Undef<T> = Exclude<T, undefined>

type ColumnAnd = { and?: any }
type ColumnOr = { or?: any }
type ColumnType<T, M extends { and?: any, or?: any }> = T & { and?: M['and'], or?: M['or'] }
type DeColumn<T> = T extends ColumnType<infer U, infer G> ? U : T
type DeColumnAll<T> = { [P in keyof T]: DeColumn<T[P]> }

export class Contact {
  age: ColumnType<string, { and?: 'user' }>
  name: ColumnType<string, { or?: 'lastName' | 'firstName' }>
  firstName: ColumnType<string, { and?: 'lastName', or?: 'name' }>
  lastName: ColumnType<string, { and?: 'firstName', or?: 'name' }>
  user: ColumnType<number, { or?: 'userId' }>
  userId: ColumnType<number,  { or?: 'user' }>
}

// ANCHOR Keys

/** provides union of and keys, for a particular prop */
type AndKeysHelper<T, P extends keyof T> = Undef<T[P] extends { and?: any } ? T[P]['and'] : never>
type AndKeys<T, P extends keyof T> = unknown extends AndKeysHelper<T, P> ? undefined : AndKeysHelper<T, P>
namespace AndKeys { 
  type ExampleA = AndKeys<Contact, 'name'>
  type ExampleB = AndKeys<Contact, 'firstName'>
}

/** provides union of and keys, with prop key */
type AndPlusKeys<T, P extends keyof T> = Undef<P | AndKeys<T, P>>
namespace AndKeysPlus {
  type ExampleA = AndPlusKeys<Contact, 'name'>
  type ExampleB = AndPlusKeys<Contact, 'firstName'>
  type ExampleC = AndPlusKeys<Contact, 'user'>
}

/** provides union of or keys, for a particular prop */
type OrKeys<T, P extends keyof T> = Undef<T[P] extends { or?: any } ? T[P]['or'] : never>
namespace OrKeys { 
  type ExampleA = OrKeys<Contact, 'name'>
  type ExampleB = OrKeys<Contact, 'firstName'>
}

/** provides AndKeys + OrKeys */
type AndOrKeys<T, P extends keyof T> = Undef<AndKeys<T, P> | OrKeys<T, P>>
namespace AndOrKeys { 
  type ExampleA = AndOrKeys<Contact, 'name'>
  type ExampleB = AndOrKeys<Contact, 'firstName'>
}

/** provides AndKeyPlus + OrKeys */
type AndPlusOrKeys<T, P extends keyof T> = Undef<AndPlusKeys<T, P> | OrKeys<T, P>>
namespace AndPlusOrKeys { 
  type ExampleA = AndPlusOrKeys<Contact, 'name'>
  type ExampleB = AndPlusOrKeys<Contact, 'firstName'>
}

// ANCHOR Props

type LockKeyofT<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? K : never

type SelfProp<T, P extends keyof T> = Pick<T, P>
namespace SelfProp { 
  type ExampleA = SelfProp<Contact, 'name'>
  type ExampleB = SelfProp<Contact, 'firstName'>
}

type AndProps<T, P extends keyof T> = Pick<T, LockKeyofT<T, AndKeys<T, P>>>
namespace AndProps { 
  type ExampleA = AndProps<Contact, 'name'>
  type ExampleB = AndProps<Contact, 'firstName'>
}

type AndPlusProps<T, P extends keyof T> = Pick<T, LockKeyofT<T, AndPlusKeys<T, P>>>
namespace AndPlusProps {
  type ExampleA = AndPlusProps<Contact, 'name'>
  type ExampleB = AndPlusProps<Contact, 'firstName'>
  type ExampleC = AndPlusProps<Contact, 'user'>
}

type OrProps<T, P extends keyof T> = Pick<T, LockKeyofT<T, OrKeys<T, P>>>
namespace OrProps {
  type ExampleA = OrProps<Contact, 'name'>
  type ExampleB = OrProps<Contact, 'firstName'>
  type ExampleC = OrProps<Contact, 'user'>
}

type ElseAndPlusKeys<T, P extends keyof T> = Exclude<keyof T, AndPlusKeys<T, P>>
type ElseAndPlusProps<T, P extends keyof T> = Pick<T, LockKeyofT<T, ElseAndPlusKeys<T, P>>>
namespace ElseAndPlusProps {
  type ExampleA = ElseAndPlusProps<Contact, 'name'>
  type ExampleB = ElseAndPlusProps<Contact, 'firstName'>
  type ExampleC = ElseAndPlusProps<Contact, 'user'>
}

type ElseOrKeys<T, P extends keyof T> = Exclude<keyof T, AndPlusKeys<T, P>>
type ElseOrProps<T, P extends keyof T> = Pick<T, LockKeyofT<T, ElseOrKeys<T, P>>>
namespace ElseOrProps {
  type ExampleA = ElseOrProps<Contact, 'name'>
  type ExampleB = ElseOrProps<Contact, 'firstName'>
  type ExampleC = ElseOrProps<Contact, 'user'>
}

type BuildMerger<T, P extends keyof T> = StrictUnion<AndPlusProps<T, P> | OrProps<T, P>>
namespace BuildMerger {
  // This works which is good:
  const a: BuildMerger<Contact, 'name'> = {
    name: 'Thomas Reggi',
  }
  // This works which is good:
  const b: BuildMerger<Contact, 'name'> = {
    firstName: 'Thomas',
    lastName: 'reggi',
  }
  // This fails which is good:
  // const c: BuildMerger<Contact, 'name'> = {
  //   name: 'Thomas Reggi',
  //   firstName: 'Thomas',
  //   lastName: 'reggi',
  // }
}

type Build<T> = UnionToIntersection<{ [P in keyof T]: BuildMerger<T, P> }[keyof T]>
namespace Build {
  type m = Build<Contact>
  const a: m = {
    name: 'Thomas Reggi', // why is this NEVER!?!?!
  }
}
```